# DNS not working on WSL

Tags: windows, internet, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently using an Insider build of Windows 11. (22458)

However, I had this problem a few times on other builds. (and wsl worked before)

When I start wsl, I'm not able to do a DNS request. (Pinging an IP address directly works.)

I tracked this problem down to the file: /etc/resolv.conf

It includes the DNS server address.

The default is:  172.22.192.1

However, this one doesn't work.

If I change it to 1.1.1.1 (Cloud Flare DNS) it works again.

However, after every restart of wsl it changes it back to the default.

There is a file called wsl.conf in which I can disable generating this file, but if always just deletes the file entirely after every reboot.

So how can I fix this?

My first Idea was to completely reset wsl, but neither resetting the app, nor reinstalling WSL via features fixed it.

Does anyone have another idea what to do?

Comment: Are you using a VPN that might change the resolver when it is active?

Comment: Just a heads-up that I've deleted my answer since it was for WSL/Ubuntu on Windows 10, and Win 11 definitely behaves differently.  I'll try to see if I can figure out how to fix it on Ubuntu under Windows 11.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds OMG I just realized the problem is my firewall. Its blocking the DNS request from the linux VM. What is WSL listed as in firewall settings, so I can whitelist it? Or even better, how can I select that the Connection to WSL is a private network?

Comment: Interesting - Are you sure its the Windows Firewall that's blocking it?  My Win11 VM is set to Public for the VM itself, but I can still connect to it through RDP, and the WSL instances within it are resolving DNS with no problem.  I don't know of a way to change the WSL vNIC to Private -- In fact, in Windows 11, the vNIC seems to be hidden from the Windows UI entirely (but still shows up with ipconfig).  But I'm wondering if maybe the Pi-hole could be refusing the WSL instance?

Comment: Anyway, what happens if you (temporarily) change the entire Win11 network profile to "Private" (if you are on a "safe" network, at least) - Any difference in how WSL responds?  (also, thanks for @tagging me so that I got a notification!)

Comment: Also, given that we're thinking this is more a problem on the Windows side (it's definitely *not* Ubuntu related), and you haven't had any other replies from anyone on Ask Ubuntu, it might be time to delete this one and recreate the question on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: And a potentially relevant [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1496354/1210833).  At least as of two years ago it wasn't possible to set the WSL vNIC to private.  I haven't seen any indication that it would be different, but Win11 does seem to have some pretty substantial changes in this area.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Ok, I guess I'll head over to the Microsoft community. I'll try to figure out how to change the Network profile to private (Its showing as unidentified in windows security and not at all in network settings). The actual problem was that I had selected for the Windows firewall to block anything incoming when connected to a public network. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds In case you want to take a look at the question, here is a link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-the-wsl-network-profile-from-public-to/c62b7bc3-8faf-44bc-8b67-848357352534

Answer (score 33):

As stated by most answers out there, creating the following configuration files and then restarting WSL should be enough:

**/etc/wsl.conf**

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

However, for some reason my `resolv.conf` keep getting recreated on every boot.

So I had to make it immutable, like so:

```sh
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

Many times this issue has bothered me, I ended up making this simple helper code:

https://github.com/epomatti/wsl2-dns-fix-config

Comment: Thanks @David I've edited it.

Comment: This worked for me however it seems something creates a symlink for resolv.conf to another file. I had to delete the symlink first. Might be a newer version of WSL. The changes survived a WSL restart.

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: One additional note for this: reboot the WSL distribution after making the change to `wsl.conf`. The setting to not overwrite `resolv.conf` is only respected after the next boot, so if you modify `resolv.conf` in the same session, your changes will still be overwritten one last time (hopefully).

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq` to see about the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink. Ubuntu network administration has gotten more (or less) complex as `systemd` has taken over.

Answer (score 9):

This is a problem with WSL, not Ubuntu or Windows.  There are lots of solutions out there, the best one I found https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6

> It also includes VPN info, but the steps work without the VPN also.
>
> 1. Run these commands in the Ubuntu terminal.
>
>    ```
>    cd ~/../../etc # Go to etc folder in WSL.
>    echo "[network]" | sudo tee wsl.conf # Create wsl.conf file and add the first line.
>    echo "generateResolvConf = false" | sudo tee -a wsl.conf # Append wsl.conf the next line.
>    wsl --terminate Debian # Terminate WSL in Windows cmd, in case the OS is Ubuntu not Debian.
>    cd ~/../../etc # Go to etc folder in WSL.
>    sudo rm -Rf resolv.conf # Delete the resolv.conf file.
>    ```
> 2. In Windows cmd, PowerShell or terminal with the VPN connected do: `Get-NetIPInterface` or `ipconfig /all` for getting the DNS primary
>    and secondary.
> 3. With the DNS primary and secondary gotten from step 2. replace the numbers in the next step in the X.X.X.X
> 4. `echo "nameserver X.X.X.X" | sudo tee resolv.conf` (Create resolv.conf and append the line.)
> 5. `echo "nameserver X.X.X.X" | sudo tee -a resolv.conf` (Append the line in resolv.conf)
> 6. `wsl --terminate Debian` (Terminate WSL in Windows cmd, in case is Ubuntu not Debian).
> 7. `sudo chattr +i resolv.conf`
> 8. Finally in Windows cmd, PowerShell or terminal:
>
>    ```
>    Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
>    ```
>
> Credit: @MartinCaccia, @yukosgiti, @machuu and @AlbesK:
> https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277
> https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4246

Comment: potentially you could add a uudecode into the chain and make what you're doing even more cryptic

Answer (score 3):

WSL is getting its IP address (and it's DNS server, netmask and other stuff) from Windows' DHCP Server. Either fix it on Windows, or fix the DNS server on 172.22.192.1.

This is a Windows problem, not a Ubuntu problem.

And No, I don't know how Windows does DHCP.

Comment: Hi, the problem is: I dont have a DNS on this IP. I dont even know what this IP is. Windows is getting its DNS from my router at 192.168.178.1.

Comment: @LightJack05 well, you do have a DNS (forwarder) on that IP similar to how systemd-resolved sets up one on 127.0.1.1. The problem is that it gets broken by some network changes, and it would be best to fix that breakage. Unfortunately I haven't seen a good fix for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

## windows wsl dns issue fixdns

1. Inside WSL2, create or append file: /etc/wsl.conf
2. Put the following lines in the file in order to ensure the your DNS changes do not get blown away

   ```
   echo "[network]" | sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf
   echo "generateResolvConf = false" | sudo tee -a /etc/wsl.conf
   ```
3. **In a cmd window**, run `wsl --shutdown`
4. Start WSL2
5. Run the following inside WSL2

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
   sudo cat << EOF > /etc/resolv.conf
   search domain.local
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 1.1.1.1
   EOF
   ```

Comment: Those public resolvers are not adequate replacement for the resolver provided in DHCP. In most company environments anyway, and it's usually VPNs and similar things that break the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the VPN Ethernet Adaptor's DNS server settings are not taken by the WSL.
These steps worked for me to add these settings manually: https://gist.github.com/akshayhiremath/1b3bff527b3eca6cd41cf60ce88f3a56/8570f9fb4dbd681fc7aabcc817fa18cbab5f1e86#file-fix-wsl2-dns-resolution

I have forked and updated the steps by
https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter to make them easier.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING!!! THIS WILL DELETE YOUR WSL**

In my case changing the wsl.conf and resolve.conf just didn't work anymore. In the end I dropped the wsl distro using the command:

```
wsl --unregister <distro-name>
```

Than I opened the microsoft store and installed ubuntu 22.04. There it worked out of the box.. finally after hours trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running Cisco AnyConnect VPN, and the WSL container was locked out from the outside world. I shutdown the VPN connection and it worked as expected. Hence, be aware that the VPN connection will not permit WSL to see the outside world, as of the time of this post.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-2---check-requirements-for-running-wsl-2

```
cmd run as admin
wsl --shutdown
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

Then you can start wsl.

Comment: Not related in any way to the question...